# `launchctl export` command not working?

Tags: command-line, high-sierra, launchd

According to the man page of `launchctl`, there is an `export` command:

```
export   Export all of the environment variables of launchd for use in a shell eval
         statement.
```

However, when I try to use this command, I get the following message.

```
Unrecognized subcommand: export
Usage: launchctl <subcommand> ... | help [subcommand]
```

What's going on here? Did the command exist at some point, but was removed for some reason, and someone forgot to update the man page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8451241) `launchctl export` is just gone.

FWIW `launchctl dumpstate` appears to contain that info (and much much more), so given enough effort, one could parse it out of there, I guess.